# When calling CreateDocumentAsync(), do I need to check the ResourceResponse<Document> for errors?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When calling CreateDocumentAsync(), do I need to check the ResourceResponse for errors? For example, there is a .StatusCode property.

Or will try-catch handle all possible error conditions?

Comment: Done, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try catch is the way,

```
try
{
    //Get a Document client
    using (client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey))
    {
        RunDemoAsync(databaseId, CollectionId).Wait();
    }
}
catch (DocumentClientException de)
{
    Exception baseException = de.GetBaseException();
    Console.WriteLine("{0} error occurred: {1}, Message: {2}", de.StatusCode, de.Message, baseException.Message);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Exception baseException = e.GetBaseException();
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}, Message: {1}", e.Message, baseException.Message);
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("End of demo, press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```